# android emulator displays different than in preview

Tags: android, emulation

Today I've encountered some strange behavior of the emulator and I don't know how to fix it.

I'm going through some tutorial on how to create audio player. In my preview it looks like:
[image]

Yet when I launch the emulator (which is set to the corresponding parameters: Nexus 5.7", 1440x2560:560dpi,api 21) it looks like this:
[image]

which is totally not the same.

What could be the reason for this? 
Is it something with code that's not reflected in the preview or I messed up with emulator choosing/configurating?

**EDIT:**

[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/) is the tutorial.

**EDIT2**

`player.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#636363"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Nagłówek playera !-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/player_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_player_header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <!-- Tytuł piosenki !-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#04b3d2"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/title_song"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />

        <!-- Playlist button !-->
        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="@string/playlist_open"
            android:id="@+id/songTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_playlist"
            android:background="@null"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Miniaturka dla piosenki !-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/songThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/player_header">

            <ImageView
                android:contentDescription="@string/song_thumnail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxHeight="260dp"
                android:src="@drawable/footer"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Player Footer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_footer_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_player_footer"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!-- Przyciski !-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <!-- Poprzedni !-->
            <ImageButton
                android:contentDescription="@string/previous_song"
                android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/img_btn_previous"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

            <!--  Wstecz !-->
            <ImageButton
                android:contentDescription="@string/backward_song"
                android:id="@+id/btnBackward"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/img_btn_backward"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

            <!-- Play !-->
            <ImageButton
                android:contentDescription="@string/play_song"
                android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/img_btn_play"
                android:background="@null" />

            <!-- Play !-->
            <ImageButton
                android:contentDescription="@string/forward_song"
                android:id="@+id/btnForward"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/img_btn_forward"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

            <!-- Następny !-->
            <ImageButton
                android:contentDescription="@string/next_song"
                android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/img_btn_next"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- ProgressBar / SeekBar !-->
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/player_footer_bg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seek_handler"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"/>

    <!-- Timer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/timerDisplay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/songProgressBar"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <!-- Obecny czas trwania !-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songCurrentDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#eeeeee"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="0:00" />

        <!-- Całkowity czas trwania !-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sontTotallDurationLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#04cbde"
            android:text="4:50"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="end"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- Przyciski Powtórz i Mieszaj !-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/timerDisplay"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!-- Przycisk Powtórz !-->
        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="@string/repeat_song"
            android:id="@+id/btnRepeat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_repeat"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="@null"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnShuffle"
            android:contentDescription="@string/shuffle_song"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_shuffle"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:background="@null"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your code or tutorial link here.

Comment: Also please explain what do you expect when you say "which is totally not the same". Is this the player controls which are bigger or something else?

Comment: @cricket_007 But I've written I ran it on nexus 6..

Comment: maybe I am wrong but it's normal behavior of emulator. If you would make a RecyclerView it would not show any elements until you mock them

Answer (score 1):

Well, I really don't know why it's not working. I've created an new app and i have a toolbar at preview

I put here my configuration - compare with yours. First, `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.example.piotr.myapplication"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Then my `styles.xml` file:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Finally `main.xml` layout (already empty):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.piotr.myapplication.MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope you find a missing element

Comment: Well, then it's weird, I have it all exactly the same, the only difference is that in layout I have set different padding.. :/ Anyway, thank You for Your time, I hope I'll get to know why it's like that.

Comment: in layout manager you have 21 setted change it to 23. I see that you have toolbar but it has different style, try to change `Holo`

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be that preview of your activity in Android Studio is a just a content of your app without toolbar.

I'm pretty sure, that you have already two xml layout files - one which shows you content of your activity and the second one that is layout of your activity, bu may shows only toolbar, as the content is there just included.

Don't expect too much from Preview`in`Layout Manager` - it only may help you with designing your app layout, but it would not give you that great direct experience as emulator or physical device.

You would find some similar issues in your daily work with android, for example: if you would make an app with `RecyclerView` like weather app Sunshine form Udacity course (I highly recommend you this course: Developing android apps).

If you have any questions or if something is still unclear to you, please feel free to ask

Comment: Actually, I only had one xml layout file that looks exactly as in the tutorial I've given a link to..

Comment: edit yoyr post and put full content of this file :-)

Comment: I've updated that, thanks:) P.S. Does the theme for the preview chosen matter in this case? I mean if I choose `AppTheme` or `HoloLight`, etc?

Comment: well, it shouldn't matter. change `tools:context` adding full name of your app  struct like `tools:context="com.example.piotr.myapplication.MainActivity"`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't change anything. Is there a possibility to include toolbar in preview or remove it from app?